# Istio traffic management with nginx-ingress working but only for port 80

Tags: istio, nginx-ingress

I've seen something strange where I've been able to have an nginx-ingress with an injected sidecar (i.e. part of the mesh) successfully route traffic that it receives into a cluster based on a k8s ingress definition, and then apply Istio traffic routing to route traffic as desired internally, but this only works when the traffic is being sent to the k8s services via port 80, and only when that is a port that is NOT served by the associated k8s service.  This tells me my success is likely some kind of hack.

I'm asking if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong and/or why this is working.  (I need to use the nginx ingress here, I can't switch to using istio-ingressgateway for this.)

My configuration / ability to reproduce this is documented in full on this github project: https://github.com/bob-walters/nginx-istio which I've created to provide a way to repeat this setup.

My setup:

- a standard Istio installation in a k8s cluster (docker desktop) with the namespaces configured to do automatic sidecar injection.
- an nginx-ingress deployment ([file](https://github.com/bob-walters/nginx-istio/blob/main/nginx-ingress-release-values.yaml)) with injected istio sidecar.

  - configured the nginx-ingress with these values in order to ensure that the sidecar would not try to handle inbound traffic but should permit the outbound traffic to go to the sidecar:

```
  podAnnotations:
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
    traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "80,443"
```

- A set of (demo) services based on podinfo representing the different services that I want to route between via Istio virtual services.  Each serving on port 9898 with type: ClusterIP (i.e. only accessible via ingress)
- A k8s Ingress definition ([file](https://github.com/bob-walters/nginx-istio/blob/main/podinfo-ingress-v3.yaml)) for the nginx-ingress which carries out the routing for some fictitious hostnames to the different podinfo deployments.  The ingress includes the following specific annotations:

  - The annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"` is set in order to ensure that the nginx-ingress uses the cluster IP address, rather than individual pod IP addresses, when forwarding traffic.
  - The annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: nginx-cache-v2.whitelabel-dev.svc.cluster.local` is **NOT** set.  Many articles will indicate that you should typically set this in combination with the above, but setting this has the effect of altering the Host header to the value specified, and Istio routes based on the Host header, so setting this would require that all Istio routing rules be specified in terms of those hostnames and not the original hostnames.  More details on this can be found at: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3171
- Finally: a Virtual Service ([file](https://github.com/bob-walters/nginx-istio/blob/main/istio-virtualservice.yaml)) for one of the hosts (same hostname given in the ingress definition) which is meant to apply once the traffic reaches the Istio cluster, and carries out routing based on a cookie header.  (It's doing weighted service shifting with a cookie to pin user sessions.)

Here's the oddity:

- The Istio traffic management seems to apply correctly if the target port of the ingress is 80.  If it's 9898 (as you would expect because that is the service's available port), the Istio traffic management doesn't seem to apply at all.

This is what I'm seeing as I try varying the port numbers:

| Target Port of Ingress Rule | K8s Service Port | Virtual service Port | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80 | 9898 | not set | virtual service works as desired |
| 9898 | 9898 | not set | routes to K8s Service. Virtual service has no effect |
| 8080 | 9898 | not set | fails: timeout/502 while attempting to invoke service |
| 9898 | 9898 | 9898 | routes to K8s Service. Virtual service has no effect |
| 443 | 9898 | not set | fails: timeout/502 while attempting to invoke service |

I'm really confused as to why this is not working with port 9898, but is working for port 80, especially given that K8s reports my ingress definition as invalid.  My understanding of the routing is that the inbound traffic would go to the 'controller' container in the nginx-ingress service, bypassing the istio proxy as long as it comes in on ports 80 or 443.  The outbound traffic should all be going through the proxy destined for the ClusterIP addresses of the k8s services, but with the 'Host' header still containing the original requested host.  Thus Istio should be able to handle its routing responsibilities based on Host + Port, and does so, but only if I am routing into the mesh with port 80.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also submitted https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/36705.  One theory I have about why this is working is that the virtual service would work for the isito-ingressgateway, and so when the nginx-ingress service sends the traffic to its sidecar at port 80, it gets picked up and handled like istio ingress traffic.

Comment: Very detailed question, I will try to replicate your issue and see what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this some more and eventually got it working.
There are some specific (non-intuitive) things that have to be correctly lined up for virtual services to work with traffic handled by an nginx-ingress.  The details are at the README.md at https://github.com/bob-walters/nginx-istio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).